# Save connection to Oracle database

Tags: excel, oracle

Is there any relatively easy way to save connections to Oracle database in Excel?

When I save Excel file with imported data from oOracle I can see connections and refresh data in sheets. But if somebody else is trying to refresh data, they get a pop-up about missing connection.

Comment: How are you defining your connections?  Are you using, for example, an ODBC data source that is defined on your machine but not on everyone's machine?  Or do you have a complete connection string specified?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Sorry for a late reply. I'm simply connecting to oracle database via power querry like in this example (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-oracle-database-power-query-d7fbd231-a705-4eb7-83b3-a66bfb678395). The only difference I have found between two computers is that one has an 32 bit oracle client while the other one has 64 bit which I don't use as it was causing badimageformatexception.